# About SQL View, I have something confused

Tags: mysql, sql, view, count, phpmyadmin

I have these tables:

- `BRANCH` (Bno, Street, Area, City, Pcode, Tel_No, Fax_No)
- `STAFF` (Sno, Fname, Lname ,Address ,Tel_No ,Position, Sex, DOB, Salary, NIN, Bno)
- `PROPERTY_FOR_RENT` (Pno, Street, Area, City, Pcode, Type, Rooms, Rent, Ono, Sno, Bno)

A view `BranchStats` (`Bno, NumStaff, NumProps`) is to be created that, for any branch, indicates the number of staff members employed and the number of properties handles.

```
CREATE VIEW BranchStats
AS 
   SELECT 
       branch.Bno Bno,
       Count (Distinct Staff.Bno) NumStaff,
       Count (Distinct property_for_rent.Sno) NumProps
   FROM 
       branch
   JOIN 
       Staff ON Staff.Bno = branch.Bno
   JOIN 
       property_for_rent ON property_for_rent.Sno = Staff.Sno
   GROUP BY 
       branch.Bno
```

**Error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Distinct staff.Bno) NumStaff, Count (Distinct
>   property_for_rent.Sno) Num' at line 4

Is there any wrong in my SQL statement? Need help

Comment: I a student, just start to learn it

Comment: first step to learning pal...practically implement code/sql...if it throws error, google it...if you still don't find it, then ask here....now, are you getting any errors?

Comment: YEs said  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Distinct staff.Bno) NumStaff, Count (Distinct property_for_rent.Sno) Num' at line 4"

Comment: I try imitate the sql from another stackoverflow answer, but failed

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL (by default) does not allow a space between the function name and the opening paren.  So, try removing those spaces:

```
CREATE VIEW BranchStats AS 
   SELECT branch.Bno,
          Count(Distinct Staff.Bno) as NumStaff,
          Count(Distinct property_for_rent.Sno) as NumProps
   FROM branch JOIN 
        Staff
        ON Staff.Bno = branch.Bno JOIN 
        property_for_rent
        ON property_for_rent.Sno = Staff.Sno
   GROUP BY  branch.Bno;
```

This is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html):

> [ . . .] the parser uses the following rules
>   by default to distinguish whether their names are being used as
>   function calls or as identifiers in nonexpression context:
>
> - To use the name as a function call in an expression, there must be no whitespace between the name and the following “(” parenthesis
>     character.
> - Conversely, to use the function name as an identifier, it must not be followed immediately by a parenthesis.
>
> The requirement that function calls be written with no whitespace
>   between the name and the parenthesis applies only to the built-in
>   functions that have special considerations. `COUNT` is one such name.